# Accessing Windows Server AppFabric caching from classic ASP application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic, appfabric

I am considering using Windows Server Appfabric for it caching functionality.

I have an existing classic ASP application that I want to rewrite in ASP.NET MVC. However, I want to be able to do this "piecemeal" i.e. a few pages at a time.

The problem is session state between the ASP and ASP.Net MVC application. I could use a database but I would like to use Appfabric since it has good scalabilty, admin, etc.

My question is: Does the Appfabric caching service/functionality have an API that I could wrap in .Net and expose to my classic ASP application as a com object?

I could then change all the Session and Application caching in the classic application to use the com object i.e. Appfabric. In this way I can share session state between ASP.Net MVC and classic ASP. I will have to test the performance penalty associated with interop as well.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and to remove the invalid tag.  Feel free to keep editing it if you don't like my changes.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, you removed the asp-classic tag, but this question is very much about ASP classic, and not just .NET

Comment: @slolife: I assumed by "classic" they meant "classic" asp.net (in contrast to asp.net mvc), which isn't the same as asp classic.  But I agree that it is still ambiguous, so adding the tag back is fine until the OP confirms one way or the other.

Comment: @yuben: Did you get an answer to this question in the mean time?  Did you go with an alternative solution?  Would be good to get an answer for this question, and you can answer your own.  Also, is this asp classic (non-.net), or asp.net?

Comment: Since the OP said "expose to my classic ASP application as a com object" and mentioned interop, I am thinking that they truly meant ASP and not .NET.  If it was the case between ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC, there would be no need to COM or interop.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: There's no such thing as classic asp.net. I assume you are implying Webforms but it's not classic. See Scot Hanselmann's blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FreeASPNETTrainingVideosFromAspConfNowAvailableForDownloadOrStreaming.aspx

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I am referring to ASP Classic as in VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

I recently attended Microsoft Tech'ed and did a small lab for AppFabric caching. It does expose an API which you can use. I am sure you can modify it and make it suitable to your app.

I would recommend you writing a small test app and there are few microsoft labs you can use to try the AppFabric caching API.

Thanks,

Nimesh

Answer (score 0):

Also try NCache
http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/samples/sample.php?id=4

FRom the site:
"This sample demonstrates sharing sessions between classic ASP and ASP.NET applications using COM+ interoperability and .NET framework. This allows faster conversion of existing ASP applications into ASP.NET applications module by module in incremental iterations while running the classic ASP and the converted ASP.NET portions of your web application side by side."